# how to reload current page without losing any data in javascript its worked me on chrome but couldn't worked in safari

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is my code i have used many code but fetching data has been cleared from this script

```
<script>
                function functionrefresh() {
                        location.reload(true);();
                    }

</script>
<button type="button" class="close" onClick="functionrefresh();" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

Comment: What data?.  Also what's the extra brackets for ? `location.reload(true);();`

Comment: Keep your title short and ask the actual question in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Alternatively you can do it like this:

```
// add your url here
window.location = "https://google.com";
```

Comment: hi Akhilesh, i tried this but couldnt work in safari

Comment: try to wrap your code in settimeout function  **setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},0);** 
where you can change time from 0 to some mili seconds hope this will help.